# Mobile Safari with thumbnail view with iOS 5

Tags: ipad, ios, safari

Can I get my Mobile Safari thumbnail view back after I upgraded to iOS 5?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no, unless you jailbreak and install GridTabs

Basically, the grid view was replaced by the new tabs in Mobile Safari in iOS 5